# System.IO.FileNotFoundException for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: nuget, entity-framework-core, filenotfoundexception

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 project which uses EF Core via the Nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.  Below is the relevant PropertyGroup from the *.csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The solution builds, but at runtime, I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies.

That assembly is not in the build folder (or any subfolders such as the netstandard2.0 subfolder).  It *is* in %userprofile%\.nuget\ ...

I have tried:

- Cleaning / Rebuilding
- Clearing the Nuget cache.
- Adding
  `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` to the
  *.csproj file.
- Removing and re-adding Micrososft.EntityFrameworkCore (and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, which is also used)

Is there some other way of forcing the package to be included in the build folder (like Local Copy)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the *.csproj files and adding the following to a PropertyGroup seems to have fixed the problem (or at least provided a reasonable workaround):

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```